# Docker-volume: I am trying to make a container by using a volume which is already made

Tags: docker, windows-10, docker-volume

I am working on this problem on Windows 10 and using Git-bash.

First, I have made a volume named "myvolume" with the command:

```
docker volume create myvolume
```

And I tried to make a Ubuntu container with the command:

```
docker run -i -t --name newvolume -v myvolume:/root/ ubuntu
```

However, I get the error message:

> C:/Program Files/Docker/Docker/Resources/bin/docker.exe: Error response from daemon: create myvolume;C: "myvolume;C" includes invalid characters for a
>   local volume name, only "[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_.-]" are allowed. If you intended to pass a host directory, use absolute path.
>   See 'C:/Program Files/Docker/Docker/Resources/bin/docker.exe run --help'.

I guess the problem occurs in Windows 10, and not in the Linux environment,
but I would like to figure out it in Windows.

Anyone know this problem?

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: What happens if you use a regular command prompt, instead of git-bash? I just tested on my Win 10 machine and it works: https://i.imgur.com/noP8rRZ.png

Comment: Your volume name have `;C` characters, `Error response from daemon: create myvolume;C: "myvolume;C"` check if you are writing this good.

Comment: @Schwarz54 Thank you for replying to my question. I confirmed that it works in Cmd in Windows but not in the Git-bash. I have no idea why it doesn't work in Git-bash. Thanks again!